# Indexed arguments can't be retrieved, why?

Tags: solidity, events

> Indexed arguments will not be stored themselves. You can only search
>   for the values, but it is impossible to retrieve the values
>   themselves.

This is a quote from the following docs:

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html?highlight=topic#events

What does this mean? If I have the log object I can see the topics thus can see the indexed values..

i.e. this is an example log object, I can see the topics here: (topics = indexed arguments)

```
{'logIndex': 0, 'transactionIndex': 0, 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x473921c06e0dc928bb81455406f0436489ffabbb51f3be079b9709ddb132e933'),
'blockHash': HexBytes('0x8973f427b65c73d7fc9ead31219046bca9ec8ee82f8126d0441f3a99fa6856df'), 'blockNumber': 9, 'address': '0x345cA3e014Aaf5dcA488057592ee47305D9B3e10', 'data': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
'topics': [HexBytes('0x6a0adf17eb20399b431dc509145e9448c952cb299ead47af739fed7289c553f5'), HexBytes('0x000000000000000000000000627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57'), HexBytes('0x000000000000000000000000f17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732')], 'type': 'mined'}
```

Comment: I just found out topics are the hashed versions of values so no way to decrypt (although you can bruteforce expected value range.. i.e. age of a person) but I think this question may rise in the future so decided to keep the question open.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

You can actually get the value of the indexed values.

**Long answer**

Let's say in your logs file you get an event with indexed values

```
{
  address: '0xA339447189Ec1f4CD93A959c4eE758B4fB3ED516',
  topics:
   [ '0x6f60e5b2581736becbd13dcf6c74309cbe82ea5136dc0936a9db0273e8776261',
     '0x00000000000000000000000090f8bf6a479f320ead074411a4b0e7944ea8c9c1' ],
  data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005',
  blockNumber: 504611,
  transactionHash: '0x2f8e22fabd86f6c35faec5f613ccab3725b45c3340882a0468381b27bfda024c',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  blockHash: '0x3e92bbf536918228df236df3731a92f449161558a892f72a539911479c1ac112',
  logIndex: 0,
  removed: false,
  id: 'log_a41aab0a'
}
```

The above logs have been created using this event:

```
event ContractReached(address indexed from, uint number);
```

And the event is called with the following arguments:

```
ContractReached(msg.sender, 5);
```

You can see that the event has 2 values:

- one indexed which is `msg.sender`
- one non-indexed which is `5`

The `topics` array consist of one event signature topic and one additional topic per indexed value (in our case just one).

**Event Signature Topic**: This is equal to a Keccak-256 hash of the signature of the event in utf-8.

`sha3(ContractReached(address,uint256))` would equal to our first topic `6f60e5b2581736becbd13dcf6c74309cbe82ea5136dc0936a9db0273e8776261`

**Topic per indexed value**: These ones are 32 byte hex values of the indexed arguments, they are not hashed like the signature topic was.
We can see that this is an address (without the `0x` infront of it): `90f8bf6a479f320ead074411a4b0e7944ea8c9c1` padded up to 32 bytes.

**Data**: The non-indexed values follow the same pattern as the topics containing the indexed values. They are non-hashed 32 byte hex representations of the values. The only difference is that they are all appended to the `data` field one after another.

Because 1 hex value is equal to a nibble(4 bits or half a byte) we end with the following data string with a length of 64 nibbles (64/2 = 32 bytes).

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005`

If you then convert the hexadecimal representation of that into a decimal you would end up with `5` which is the value we passed in the event.

If our address wasn't indexed we would have received a `data` of size 128 nibbles.

e.g.`00000000000000000000000090f8bf6a479f320ead074411a4b0e7944ea8c9c10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005`

Only by eye-ing the string above you can easily see the two arguments, each being 64 nibbles.

Please feel free to correct me if anyone finds any mistake in my explanation.

Comment: Indexed arguments for simple types will be in the topics as is, for example address, uint, bytes; but types like string will be hashed with keccak256 and you will not be able to recover them.