# Event filter of a contract doesn't filter light client

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, light-clients

hello  i use the env is  android  go ethereum  light client not  web3j  not web3j
i init geth  code

> ```
>         FilterQuery selfFQ = Geth.newFilterQuery();
>         selfFQ.setTopics(Geth.newTopicsEmpty());
>         selfFQ.setAddresses(Geth.newAddressesEmpty());
>         Topics tps = selfFQ.getTopics();
>         String strFunction = "ReturnValue(address,int256)";
>         String HashStr = Sha3.hash(strFunction);
>         List<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
>         topics.add("0x" + HashStr);
>         tps.append(fromListToHashes(topics));
>         selfFQ.setTopics(tps);
>         node.getEthereumClient().subscribeFilterLogs(Geth.newContext(),selfFQ,new MyFilterLogsHandler(),16L);
> ```
>
> then i  receiver the log in bellow

```
    public void  onFilterLogs(org.ethereum.geth.Log var1){
    try{
        byte[] topics = var1.getTopics().get(0).getBytes();
        byte[] args = var1.getTopics().get(1).getBytes();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("111","onFilterLogs getTopics " + var1.toString());
    }
}
```

then  i don't know how to parse the event and param ...... anybody can told me  thanks

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39909/indexed-arguments-cant-be-retrieved-why  i have find answer about topic and indexed an unindexed   but  still dont konw how to transfer to function .....

Answer (score 0):

you will need [`abi`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html) to parse the event and inputs. I did the parsing in golang like this,

`abiParsed, err = abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(YourContract_ABI))
abiParsed.Events[eventName].Inputs.Unpack(v, rawLog.Data)`

Comment: i cannot find the any detail about abi  in geth.aar ..... maybe it's not been export in geth.aar

Comment: sorry, i dont fimilliar with mobile client. If abi not exposed, you may post a request to the eth team on github.

And, you could try BoundContract and see if it gives your any API to unpack logs.

Comment: ok i'll try it  ths a lot !